# Outlook Auto-Sync keeps re-enabling — How to ultimately deactivate it?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, sync, bugs, outlook

I've got a weird phenomenon on my Android 6.0 where Outlook Auto-Sync is automatically and silently re-enabled. I haven't figured out yet when exactly this happens but I'm deactivating Auto-Sync and deleting all imported contacts every other day. It really annoys me.

I disable Auto-Sync via Settings -> Accounts -> Outlook.

While this works fine for other accounts (e.g. GMX), Outlook is re-enabled quite too frequently.

I also tried to delete and reinstall Outlook but the bug continues to happen.

I tried to search the Internet, but all Google hits are about how to enabled/disable Auto-Sync in general. Well, I do know how to do this. But I couldn't find anything about whether this is an Android bug, an Outlook bug, or just a mysterious thing happening on my phone.

Is there another way to make sure that Auto-Sync is disabled?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it re-enables because of the security policy applied when adding the account. This happens with me too and 10000% annoying. I removed the account and threw it out.